# How to retrieve items from the cache in view in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, caching, view, laravel-views, laravel-cache

I've stored some data in Laravel 5.5 [cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/cache) in [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers)  as you can see in following:

```
class DataServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $user = Cache::rememberForever('user', function () {
            return array('name' => 'jack', 'age' => 25);
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I retrieve items from the cache in `controller` by this:

```
  $user= Cache::get('user');
```

But I need to retrieve `cache` items within `views (blade)`, How can I access them **directly** in `views (blade)` *(without passing cache as variable)*? 
I just want to store data in `cache` once, and access to it everywhere in my app **with no more steps**, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [cache helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-cache):

```
{{ cache('user')['name'] }}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Cache Facade:** `{{ Cache::get('user')['name'] }}`
**cache helper:** `{{ cache()->get('user')['name'] }}` or `{{ cache('user')['name'] }}`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
@php 
    $user = Cache::get(“user”);
@endphp

 {{ $user[“name”]; }}
```